# How to find matrices with given commutator

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

Consider $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Is it possible to find two matrices A,B
such that their commutator AB - BA equals a given matrix C?
Is there any chance to characterize all possible occuring commutators in a given
set of matrices over some fixed ring?
One specific example: C the unit matrix. Are there such A,B? To find them i would try to solve a system of equations. But is there are more systematic way to say theoretically that we cannot or can find A,B, such that AB-BA = 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the specific case of $[A,B]=I$, the answer is No over most rings - check the trace!